# how to get this script working

Tags: javascript, html

Please visit this [page](http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-broker-spreads). I want to place a link on my site to this one.
However I want the include commissions checkbox to be checked by
default when the user clicks through and goes to the page.

Any Idea how I can get this done ?

[image]

update - Below is the code I tried but the event is not taking place I am getting an error

```
<iframe id="forex"src="http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-broker-spreads" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"> <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { //want to trigger it from outside the iframe
        $("#forex").load(function(){
        $("#forex").contents().find("#includeCommission").trigger("click");
        });
      });

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a more clearer description of what you're trying to accomplish and what happens. Also include existing code. We can only help you when your issue is well-described. Also do not expect us to write code from scratch, SO is here to support you, not to do the work for you.

Comment: You must post what are you trying to do.

Comment: I think the OP wants to navigate to a page, then execute javascript functions in it.

Comment: yes, I want to navigate to a page and then execute the js function Thanks Shimmy

Comment: Cross Domain access is prevented in browsers. So u cant access element in an iframe which belongs to another domain. In order to do so the parent and the iframe source should be in the same domain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020479/iframe-crossdomain-cannot-interact . Read this

Comment: I am posting this as an answer so that it might be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross Domain access is prevented in browsers. So u cant access element in an iframe which belongs to another domain. In order to do so the parent and the iframe source should be in the same domain .[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020479/iframe-crossdomain-cannot-interact)